# Android Navigation Drawer three line hamburger icon

Tags: android, hamburger-menu

I'm going crazy trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and tried all the solutions on SO but still seem to be missing something. This is the first time I am creating a navigation drawer and took the help of an online tutorial.

Everything works great, except the icon shows the back arrow instead of the three lines.

The first bunch of answers deal with the v4 library tied to the drawable icon which didn't apply to me since I am using the v7 library
On the v7, the first answer I tried was to use below, but still remained as arrow.

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }
```

I also tried this trick, but same result:

```
drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawerToggle.syncState();
            }
```

I then decided to give up and try to just force the icon and downloaded the ic_drawer icon and used below to just set it and be done, but still no go:

```
 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

I then went so far as to remove everything tied to making the icon to start from scratch, but even after making my code just as below, the back arrow still persists and clicking it opens the navigation drawer:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navDrawer);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close) {
};
```

Even if I comment out the toolbar and that drawer toggle to have nothing in my onCreate, I am now still stuck with that back arrow. The navigation drawer still works great and opens when I click on it. I just don't know where that back arrow is coming from so I can kill it and try to work back the other code to get the three lines to show up.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the code in full. With all the navigation drawer stuff commented out, I can still see the back arrow, and pressing it or swiping opens the fragment perfectly. If I take the comments off, its still the same thing

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {


    public ArrayList<String> strTrips = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adpTrips;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    //String[] strDefaultList={"Click the '+' on the toolbar to add a new trip","","Once you have at least one trip, you select it to view/enter information"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Initialize toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);






       /* DrawerLayout drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navDrawer);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close) {
          @Override
           public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
               super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
               //getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
               //drawerToggle.syncState();
           }

           @Override
           public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
               super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
               //getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
              // drawerToggle.syncState();
           }


       };*/

    /*    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
*/
        //drawerToggle.syncState();
       /* drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //drawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });*/




        subLoadTrips();

    }

/*
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //drawerToggle.syncState();
    }
*/
```

The manifest file is below. The activity where I am adding the NavigationDrawer is 'Main'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dimbu.tripx"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".AddTrip">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Main" />

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post the complete setup code as you have it now, instead of just snippets.

Comment: Not sure why it won't format code sections as code...I selected the text and pressed CTRL+K so that it added the empty line and the 8 spaces in front of each line

Comment: Thanks Henry, taking the bullets off worked!

Comment: Hi Mike, I have updated to show what I have now. When I run this with all the navigation drawer sections commented, I can still see the back arrow and pressing it opens the fragment, or swiping also opens it. Please let me know if I should add anything else

Comment: Wouldn't that be these two lines of code towards the bottom?
`
        /*drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        */  //drawerToggle.syncState();`

even when I run with all those lines uncommented including those two I am still stuck with the back arrow

Comment: Ah, I had to refresh the page.

Comment: Show activity definition from manifest, please

Comment: Hi Danil, I just added it. Also just to note...the second activity 'AddTrip' I had there the getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); method to give a way to return to 'Main' activity. I even got desperate enough to try disabling that but no effect on the Main activity

Comment: You're setup looks fine; you just need to un-comment everything, except the extra `syncState()` calls, and the `getActivity()` stuff, 'cause you're not in a `Fragment`. Are you calling `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` on the toggle anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Hi Mike, I uncommented everything. Took off the syncState call under the onDrawerOpened, onDrawerClosed methods, but left it in the onPostCreate and drawerLayout.post methods.

I'm still stuck with the back arrow. Any other ideas?

Comment: Clean/rebuild your project. And make sure you're not disabling the drawer indicator anywhere.

Comment: wow...you won't believe how many times I deleted all the code and started from scratch thinking I made a mistake somewhere and I was so close to banging my head against a wall.

I ran 'clean project', followed by 'rebuild project' and ran it and it came out perfect...I see the three lines as expected and everything works great.

Two questions:
- How do I mark your answer as the correct answer.
- I am very new and this is only my second app. Is this something I should be doing quite often? I never had to do it on my first app and never thought of even trying it figuring code is code.

Comment: You should clean/rebuild whenever your code isn't acting like you think it should. There's really no definite way to tell if you need to. Just whenever thing's are wonky. :-) It was a simple fix; no need for me to post an answer that's just "clean/rebuild". You can post one yourself, if you want, or just delete your question. Thanks, though. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Mike! I'll add it just in case some other newbie like me ends up in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

This one line code should help you. ☺

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by Mike M in comments.

With all the code being correct, his suggestion to clean/rebuild the project worked and then the changes took effect!

Answer (score -1):

`toolbar` is not your app toolbar here!

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

It's just a view. Instead of this you should get current app toolbar:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

Comment: Hi Danil, I changed the code to below, but still just the back arrow button:

`[code]
// Initialize toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
[/code]`